# Glib-Error MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I got this Error when querying MYSQL Database:

```
Glib-Error **: gmem.c:173:falied to allocate 216000000 bytes aborting..
```

Do anybody have some explanations?

I am using MYSQL Query Browser.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to run a `SELECT` query that is way too big to fit in the memory available on your computer. Try adding a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: u r right, is it query browser or is it the MYSQL? and does this affect the DB?

Comment: I believe it is just the query browser. It shouldn't affect the server, other than it is probably going to lag while trying to deal with that query.